# OCR software recommendation

Tags: text, pdf, software-recommendation

I should scan a brochure and remake it with all the text and images replacing some obsolete text like emails and old links, but preserving the pictures and text relationships. (No, I do not have any digital files).

I am looking for a software which can convert the page-images to PDFs with text and images as close as possible to original brochure.

If there is no choice I will cut all the true-images and OCR the text separately, which is quite time consuming.

Any recommendations and advices would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Acrobat pro can ocr all pages in one go

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used Abbyy Finereader for over a decade now, and it has always done a fantastic job for me. I really love the fact that, in addition to reading scanned images, it can also read fully digital PDF files, essentially rebuilding the PDF into an editable document. I don't have a lot of experience with other OCR software, but I can't imagine it getting much better than Abbyy.

The [online tool to try it out](http://www.finereaderonline.com/en-us) is fairly powerful.

Comment: Are you on Mac or Windows? If on Mac - does it allows to edit the recignised text before output? Does it preserve the page layout?

Comment: I use it on a PC, but it most likely works the same way regardless of platform. Yes. Once you have a scan (which can be triggered via the software itself) it attempts to read the text. By default it attempts to recognize both text and images and will section off each page with the appropriate type of frame. Once that is done, you can modify the recognition frames and re-read if you like. When you're happy with that, you can then perform a spell check where it shows you a zoomed split screen of the scan itself next to the interpretation. It's very good at recognizing text, but sometimes...

Comment: ...a character combination like "rn" may be interpreted as an "m," for example. Once the spell check is done, you can export to various formats including simple text, rich text, Word, etc. Oh,  it also has a table recognition tool that you can use if you want to import a table as columns and rows. I'm leaving out a lot of the bells and whistles, but I think you get the idea.

Comment: I asked because the Mac version (by the internet) has/had no option to edit the text before export... Will clarify the issue...

Comment: If you've heard that the two versions are different, then please verify that and report back. I would like to know.

Comment: All the sites write the Mac version has less functions as Win's one. I will give it try later (cannot download at the moment, it is 600mB)